# How to position a Box tag in the bottom with MUI 5

Tags: html, css, typescript, material-ui

I would like to place a Box tag in the bottom of the page.

Current Behaviour:

[image]

I want to set TextField and the send button in to bottom of the page (Browser and Mobile). and I want to keep user messages above the text field box. a message in the left side and a message in the right side like a chat. users can scroll the chat but textfield and send button should be fixed. (basically it similar to chatGPT UI).

```
import { Box, Button, Container, TextField, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { useState } from 'react';

import Header from './header';
import Nav from './nav';

const APP_BAR_MOBILE = 64;

const DashboardLayout = () => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    return (
        <Box
            sx={{
                display: 'flex',
                height: '100%',
                overflow: 'hidden',
            }}
        >
            <Nav openNav={open} onCloseNav={() => setOpen(false)} />
            <Header onOpenNav={() => setOpen(true)} />
            <Container>
                <Box
                    sx={{
                        flexGrow: 1,
                        overflow: 'auto',
                        marginTop: `${APP_BAR_MOBILE + 24}px`,
                        backgroundColor: 'pink',
                        height: "100%",
                    }}
                >
                    <Typography variant='h1'>s</Typography>

                    <Box display={"flex"}>
                        <TextField fullWidth size='small' variant='outlined' autoFocus />
                        <Button variant='contained' sx={{ ml: 1 }}>Send</Button>
                    </Box>
                </Box>
            </Container>
        </Box>
    );
};

export default DashboardLayout;
```

I added CSS for body and HTML to margin and padding 0;

public URL = https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-4fja9o?file=src%2Flayouts%2Fdashboard%2Findex.tsx

I tried with adding differenct position styles and added grid but does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a similar UI as `ChatGPT` using the MUI `<Drawer />` component and putting your Textfield into a `fixed` position. You can find a working example I made over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vrvbkb?file=src%2FApp.tsx).

The code will be like this, You can customize it as you need,

```
<Box display="flex">

  {/* YOUR SIDEBAR */}
  <Drawer
    variant="permanent"
    anchor="left"
    sx={{ width: 240, flexShrink: 0, '& .MuiDrawer-paper': { width: 240, boxSizing: 'border-box' } }}
  >
    <List>
      <h3>Title 01</h3>
      <h3>Title 02</h3>
    </List>
  </Drawer>

  <Box component="main" flexGrow={1} p={3}>
    <Box maxWidth="md" mx="auto">

    {/* YOUR MESSAGES*/}
      <Typography>Message 01</Typography>
      <Typography>Message 02</Typography>
    
    {/* YOUR FIXED BOX AND TEXTFIELD*/}
      <Box position="fixed" bottom={10} width="100%" bgcolor="lightgray" maxWidth="md" mx="auto">
        <TextField label="Textfield" sx={{ width: '100%' }} />
      </Box>
    </Box>
  </Box>

</Box>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for your response. but this works for desktop ui but my nav is behaving a little bit differently. I have added the URL to an editor.